# Handle variables with nested function in r

Tags: r, function

```
f1 <- function(x){
pass[4]+x
}
f2 <- function(x,y){
pass=y
f1(x)
}
f2(x=3,y=c(1,2,3,4,5))
```

The *pass* variable cannot be passes to f1 function; can anyone help me to explain why? And how can I do with the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pass` is declared within the scope of `f2`, so it is only available within the scope of `f1`. if you want to reference it in `f1`, you must pass it to `f1` as an argument.

```
f1 <- function(x, pass) {
    pass[4]+x
}
f2 <- function(x,y) {
    pass=y
    f1(x, pass)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check environment objects in the function scope

```
f1 <- function(x){
    print('f1: ')
    print(ls(envir = environment()) )
    # pass[4]+x
}
f2 <- function(x,y){
  pass=y
  print('f2: ')
  print(ls(envir = environment()) )
  f1(x)
}
f2(x=3,y=c(1,2,3,4,5))
```

try:

```
f2 <- function(x,y){
  f1 <- function(x){
    pass[4]+x
  }
  pass=y
  f1(x)
}
```